# How to hide my private key from mandrillapp in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mandrill

I have successfully created and added the key in mandrill and can send email from my javascript page hosted here:

http://goo.gl/2YSwj7

but I'm having the issue that my mandrill key is publicly visible (in contact_me.js file)

I have tried to use mandrill key option to enable key only from certain ip addresses but that does not work! ( I have entered github's ip's in key option restrictions but actually we are not sending it from there, but from users browser, right? )

If someone have some idea, how to workaround that, to send email from browser, and restrict it on that page only, I'd be very glad to hear it,

thanks, oserk+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an eternal problem that several companies are making, enabling access to APIs through JavaScript without [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) are 100% vulnerable.

There is no way to hide your private key, as long as it is in JavaScript memory it could be trapped very easily. Whenever a company show you a sample code in JavaScript with a Private Key they clearly does not follow how web security works. Just by opening the web page you could get the private key without any single effort.

You should search for JavaScript APIs that supports Oauth. What is the difference? Oauth instead of using private keys in the front end, it use them in the backend and in the front end, just store a cookie with a token, that token belongs to a single user, in the worst case of a hack, the hacker just hack one user, and he needs to hack the user computer which is more hard than just opening a web.

If a hacker takes a private key, he is hacking an entire company account. Be careful with private keys.

Comment: thanks for info, I guess that pure javascript api's are used in node environment, but I completely agree that oauth should be used! Hey what would you think would I be able to hack this with one ajax call after user  submits, to send the request to some background service of mine (heroku or similar free account could be used for that purpose) and only check if user comes from my page and do mail sending logic from there? sounds reasonable to pull that off right?

Comment: Yeah, handling on the server side is more secure, there they can't modify the "from" and "to", also you could check the if the referrer is your site, plus you limit the send rate per IP, like just send one email in 30 minutes from a given IP, and you are all set with the basic security things for a contact form email. @oserk